# Patching resource at the same time with spring data rest

Tags: database, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have an entity which uses spring data rest api for patch

```
Customer {
   Long id;
   String primaryValue;
   String secondaryValue;
}
```

In a microservice architecture, other service call spring data rest api patch call to update primaryValue and secondaryValue in two different requests and these requests can occur at the same time.

```
Request1: 
api/url PATCH
{
"id":1,
"primaryValue": "value1"
}

Request2: 
api/url PATCH
{
"id":1,
"secondaryValue": "value2"
}
```

Databse state is missing one of these values even though updates were made to have a value for each. Although database perform transactions in isolation, data rest doing a get before it does the patch and ending in a bad state when both transactions happen at the same time. I am trying to solve this issue and looking for ways to solve it

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options I see here:

1. Use an optimistic lock and throw an exception when it fails; on the client, if exception is received then try again
2. Use a database lock if possible
3. Send requests synchronously
4. Merge the patch endpoints into a single one if they always go hand in hand (if you use these two in other places you can create a third endpoint to support both)

I am not sure if there is a Hibernate way to automatically solve this, it may help you with the locks instead.

Comment: thanks  I have used optimistic lock mechanism with @Version to achieve this.